# How do I enable telnet on a D-Link DIR-878 AC1900 router?

Tags: router, telnet

How do I enable telnet on a D-Link DIR-878 AC1900 router?

I have tried everything, can someone help me?

The firmware version is 1.30 and the hardware version is A1.

If anyone wants more details, just ask me in the comments.

This is the GUI I see:

> [image]

Comment: Does [Telnet - D-Link DIR-878 User Manual Page 177](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1649659/D-Link-Dir-878.html?page=177) answer your question?

Comment: That manual is outdated, my gui ( https://i.ibb.co/y6L3zx7/Screenshot-2.png ) is completely different, but thanks for the help.

Comment: @i_Blaze Please do not add the word “Unanwered” to the title or text of a question [as you did in your edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1697217/revisions). It will not get you and answer faster. Your question is less than a few hours old. People are not sitting here just to answer your question. In the case of specific questions like this it might take time for someone to stumble across this question and answer it. Please be patient.

Comment: did you check dlink for the latest manual, if that one is outdated?

Comment: i read the manual that came with the router and there is no mention of telnet